# Some Truffle tests not running after truffle init (Mac OSX) Uncaught TypeError

Tags: macos, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am trying to build a dapp using truffle.  I have installed Testrpc and Truffle globally with NPM.  I ran testrpc in a terminal window and ran truffle test.  I get 2 passing and 3 failing tests.  The three failing tests are

```
TestMetacoin testInitialBalanceUsingDeployedContract:

TestMetacoin testInitialBalanceWithNewMetaCoin:
```

and

```
Contract: MetaCoin should send coin correctly:
```

each is failing at the same place:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ethjs-abi/lib/index.js:139:34
  at Array.map (native)
  at Object.decodeEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ethjs-abi/lib/index.js:138:6)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:73:38
  at Array.map (native)
  at Object.decodeLogs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:44:19)
  at Object.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:172:35)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:142:25
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:89:9
  at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:119:13)
  at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
  at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
  at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
```

I am sure I am missing something simple, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your contract code, and the code you are using to interface with the contract?

Comment: I can add it but it is literally the boilerplate code that comes from truffle init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug. They've fixed it.

Github issue : https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/377

So, just re-install truffle

Comment: That did it thank you!  I had tried everything and was going crazy thinking I had missed a dependency or something.